# Angular POST to confirm string exists

Tags: angular

I am trying to make this POST call to check and see if a specific string exists or not but I am not getting the results I intend to see. I would like to know should I expect return data or will it be a true or false?

POST method:

```js
public userNameExist(selectedName: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.givenURL, {"name": selectedName}).subscribe(data => {})
}
```

Where or how can I see if the name I have passed in does actually exist and if I should be getting a true or false back what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path , you could access the data and see what is result as follows

```
public userNameExist(selectedName: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.givenURL, {"name": selectedName}).subscribe((data) => console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: when i do this... regardless of the name i am getting: `{valid: false}`

Comment: Then it is an issue with back end , check the network tab what is the value being send

Comment: did you sort this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not... hopefully by tomorrow.

Comment: even though i wasn't able to resolve the api issue but what would the return result be like? i am assuming since i am passing in a string to check if it exists in the api it would return true or false correct?

Comment: ya i used postman as well i and i am still getting the same message {valid: false}

Comment: which clearly states that issue is with your backned